# Regex to match combination of letter and numbers to be used in URL pattarns in Django Project?

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I need to pass username in my URL.
username can be any combination of letter, numbers and special characters like `@`,`_`.
also, username starts with a letter.

username examples: `test@1, test_1,test2_1990,`

Comment: url(r'^user-points/(?P<username>[a-z]+)/$', I was using this for a simple username,but now i need to extend the possilibities of usernames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex for your purpose: **"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_@]*$"**

Comment: thanks a lot :) the updated one is [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_@]+)/$